# Netgear 511 wireless adapter stopped working after upgrade

Tags: 10.04, kernel, laptop, broadcom

Why will Netgear wireless adapter not work with SIMPLE netgear511 upgrade to UBUNTU 10.04 WHEN IT WAS WORKING PERFECTLY WITH 9.04

I upgaded from UBUNTU 9.04 on my IBM THINKPAD to 10.04 LTS. The NETGEAR 511 ADAPTER HAD BEEN WORKING CORRECTLY with broadband wireless. With 10.04 the access point (and no other wireless point) was being seen.

Reinstalling UBUNTU 9.04 automatically "sees" the WG 511 and permits connection to wi-fi. Something must have been changed/omitted in 10.04, but as a rank beginner w/UBUNTU, I don't know how to find out and fix it. Have so far been really impressed while trying to rehab this old IBM THINKPAD. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: We need more information, see this question for tips on what logs we need information from: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Answer (score 2):

I believe this card doesn't have a distributable firmware. Please try to install [linux-firmware-nonfree](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware-nonfree)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

and reboot.

[Bug reference](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/515424)